# Swift : How to set two action on Single Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working on a iOS app, where i have couple of tiles. When user touch one of these tiles, function tileTapped1 gets called.

I have used UITapGestureRecognizer for this as per the code below:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tileTapped1:")
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tile[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

I need your help to understand is there any way to call two function when a user the tile. For example something like this:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action1: "tileTapped1:", action2:"tileTapped2:")
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tile[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Can't you merge the 2 functions in a single one? Just like this:
`let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "newFunction:")`. And in newFunction you call tileTapped1 & 2

Comment: Can you call the second function from within the first function?

Comment: Merging them is not an option as i need first to finish processing and display changes on tiles. And then second function to start working (after a delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call addTarget:action: again on the gesture recognizer to add a second callback method.

Comment: Thanks Rounak, i will try this and let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks Rounak, it works and let me call one more function. However it doesn't solve my actual problem which i thought would be resolved if i managed to call two functions on tap.  It's actually a tic tac toe game. So everything gets called when user tap the tile. So when function exit, it put X or O there and someone win it shows an alert. I just want to put pause between events, so that a user can see what's happening. For example winning combination. In my case it goes away in mili seconds and replaced by alert window. Can you help me doing this.